# stream() method is not working with Mockito spy

Tags: java, testing, collections, mockito

Code below:

```
 List<Object> list = spy(new LinkedList<>());
 list.stream().map(item -> item);
```

is not working, causing an exception during test:

```
Cannot call real method on java interface. Interface does not have any implementation!
Calling real methods is only possible when mocking concrete classes.
  //correct example:
  when(mockOfConcreteClass.doStuff()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

However, calling `size()` is working okay. What is wrong with `stream()` method? I am using Mockito `1.8.4` ver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `java.util.List.stream()` is a default method in `java.util.Collection`. Mockito versions older than 1.10.5 (maybe 1.10.0) cannot handle default methods (it's missing the `java.lang.reflect.Method.isDefault()` check and maybe some spy-specifics for dealing with such methods).

I've verified that it works with Mockito 1.10.19, so I recommend upgrading when writing code in Java 8.

Comment: Thanks, it's working now! I have changed version to `1.10.19` like you wrote